# Display Configurable Swatches in subcategories displayed on parent category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

Having a bit of a strange issue here, with a very unique scenario.

Currently my main categories have no products, but they have a child category with products, and a grandchild category with products, that all show up on the main category page.

**list.phtml**

```
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$childCategories = $category->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$childCategories) as $childId):

$childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($childId);
```

This has allowed me to pull the product collection from the children categories just fine, as well as the child category name, description, etc. I have the full grid of products rendering just fine except for the configurable swatches.

Here is the bit of php for the configurable swatches which is misbehaving:

```
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChildren();
        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_gcProduct);
            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
        }
}
```

It doesn't render anything. However if I put an 'echo "Hello!";' after the if statement, that shows up.. so it thinks it's true. I've tried changing $this to $childCategories (which can be used to access the full category) but still nothing shows up for the swatches.

Any suggestions/ideas?